# Segmentation fault in wildcard pattern matching

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault, dynamic-programming

I am getting Segmentation fault in wildcard pattern matching in interviewBit and i seeked Help only to get no response by now.
I am using  DP to solve the task.
Please help me figure out the reason of The segFault
Link to the problem -- https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/regular-expression-match/

Here is my solution getting segFault in C++ .

```
int Solution::isMatch(const string &s, const string &p) {

    int n=s.size(),m=p.size();
    bool dp[n+1][m+1];

   for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)for(int j=0;j<=m;j++)dp[i][j]=false;
   dp[0][0]=true;

   for(int j=1;j<=m;j++)
      if(p[j-1]=='*')dp[0][j]=dp[0][j-1];

   for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
   {
      for(int j=1;j<=m;j++)
      {
         if(s[i-1]==p[j-1] || p[j-1]=='?')dp[i][j]=dp[i-1][j-1];
         else if(p[j-1]=='*')
         {
            int v1=dp[i][j-1],v2=0;// Not Using
            v2=(dp[i-1][j]|dp[i][j-1]);
            dp[i][j]=(v1|v2);
         }
         else dp[i][j]=false;
      }
   } 
   return dp[n][m];
}
```

Comment: seems like you're getting it during runtime, what are the string values that cause the error?

Comment: `bool dp[n+1][m+1];`  This is not legal C++,  Arrays in C++ must be declared using compile-time expressions as the number of entries.  Use `std::vector` instead, not only to make it standard C++, but to aid you in debugging your issue, since `vector` has an `at()` function that throws an exception if you go out of bounds (instead of seg fault).

Comment: @EmrahIzci The string values are not provided !

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks, I will try out using Vectors...

Comment: @SandeepKumar use `std::vector<std::vector<bool>> dp(n+1, std::vector<bool>(m+1));` and replace your accesses using `[ ]` with `at()` (for both the string and vector).  Then if you go out of bounds, an `out_of_range` exception will be thrown instead of a seg fault.  Then you will just need to see which access threw the exception and fix the issue.  Using non-standard arrays and `[ ]` doesn't come with this "debugging feature" -- only `at()` has these characteristics.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks, It works like charm now.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate dynamic memory

```
bool** dp = new bool*[n+1];
for(bool i = 0; i < n+1; ++i)
    dp[i] = new bool[m+1];
```

Since you don't need any custom action on the data, just an array will suffice, there is no need for vector.

Comment: What is this "custom action" you're speaking of?  The fact that vector dynamically allocates memory without having to do any loops and calling `new[]` as you have done is what it's designed for.  Also, you didn't mention `delete[]` and how that has to be called.

Comment: The only feature that vector adds that helps the programmer in solving the problem is 1) Not having to manually manage memory, and maybe just as important, 2) the `at()` function to test for boundary access errors.  Using `new[]` or even regular arrays (and even non-standard VLA's) does not have this debugging feature.  And according to the poster, it seems the problem was solved due to vector, and possibly using `at()`.